# Get the data type of a PyTorch tensor

Tags: pytorch

I understand that PyTorch tensors are homogenous, ie, each of the elements are of the same type.

How do I find out the type of the elements in a PyTorch tensor?

Answer (score 24):

There are three kinds of things:

```
dtype                   || CPU tensor               || GPU tensor

torch.float32              torch.FloatTensor           torch.cuda.FloatTensor
```

The first one you get with `print(t.dtype)` if `t` is your tensor, else you use `t.type()` for the other two.

Answer (score 17):

Use the [`dtype` attribute](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensor_attributes.html#torch-dtype):

```
>>> import torch
>>> print(torch.Tensor(1).dtype)
torch.float32
```

The documentation also gives the [canonical list of datatypes](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensor_attributes.html#torch-dtype).

Comment: How do you get the class types? Is there a way to do  that in Pytorch?

Comment: @Breeze can you give an example of what you mean?